# clean Off! bug spray stain on car's handle?

Tags: cleaning

How can I  clean Off! Deep Woods Insect Repellent Spray off the car's handle and other plastic exterior parts ?

Comment: What kind of stain did this cause? I've used the product, but I'm not familiar with this being a problem.

Answer (score 2):

If the plastic is black, there are special car detailing (cleaning) products which remove white haze from the black plastic. Your local car shop will probably stock some. Stick with reputable brands like Meguiars, Autoglym, etc. The cheaper ones tend not to last, and the "stain" comes back after the product eventually washes off. Try Autoglym Bumper & Trim Gel, Meguiar’s Ultimate Black Plastic Restorer etc.
You can also ask your local car repair shop, or look up a local car detailer and ask them what they use.
I have tried other home remedies on occasion but they don't last, and can even make the problem worse once the "quick fix" is gone/washed off e.g. orange oil